# JavaScript generated input tag not displaying text

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Ive been attempting to insert an input tag into the DOM with JavaScript.The problem arises when I set the innerHTML property of the input tag to some text.

One thing I noticed was that in Chrome developer tools the JavaScript generated input had a closing tag. Isn't the input tag a self closing tag?

When I checked developer tools I get no errors. Also, when I inspect the elements the input tag will appear along with the associated text but it will not appear on the window. Any idea, what causes this issue?

```
//javascript
function Survey() {}

Survey.prototype.displaySurvey = function() {
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("action", "none");
form.setAttribute("method", "get");
document.body.appendChild(form);

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("name", "prod");
input.setAttribute("type", "text");
input.innerHTML = "product";
form.appendChild(input);
}

window.onload = main;

function main() {
  var survey = new Survey();
  survey.displaySurvey();
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>form test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="survey1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input>`'s do not have `innerHTML` - they have a `value`

Answer (score 1):

Won't work. [Per the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> **Permitted content** None, it is an empty element.

If you need text in there, edit the `value` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you just want to add an input with the value "option" change your javaScript to the following. This will create an input field inside the newly created div with the id "content".

```
function Survey() {}

Survey.prototype.displaySurvey = function() {
   var form = document.createElement("form");
   form.setAttribute("action", "none");
   form.setAttribute("method", "get");
   document.body.appendChild(form);

   /*var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.setAttribute("name", "prod");
   input.setAttribute("type", "text");
   input.innerHTML = "product";
   form.appendChild(input);*/
   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML ="<input type='text' name='prod' value='product' />";
}

function main() {
  var survey = new Survey();
  survey.displaySurvey();
}

//window.onload = main;
window.onload = function(){
    main();
};
```

And your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>form test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="survey1.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why did you do window.onload = function() { main(); }; instead of window.onload = main; ?

Comment: I did that because when I tested it locally I couldn't get it to work with just `window.onload = main;` for some reason. However if it works doing it your way that is fine. `window.onload = function() { main(); };` Allows you to do multiple thing on the onload event. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: I just tested it again with `window.onload = main;` and it works fine lol. It may had just been due to a bug in my testing. good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries! don't forget to mark it as the correct answer if it worked.